# Setting callback function of parent class

Tags: javascript, inheritance, parameters, callback

I am trying to set a call back function (pass it as a param) to a parent class, but when using it I get "this.getYValuesCB is not a function" I tried passing it in constructor, and tried binding to "this" but still same problem.

Any pointer will be appreciated.

Thanks!

```
export class D3Chart {
    constructor() {
        this.getYValuesCB = null;   // also tried setting it here
    }
    setYValuesCb(cb) {
        this.getYValuesCB = cb;
    }
    ticks = data => Math.max(...data.map( rec => { this.getBookingSum(rec) }));    // when using  this it says this.getBookingSum is not a function!
}

export default class BookingsChart extends D3Chart {
    constructor(data, svgDevId) {
        super(data, svgDevId, 'booking');
    }
    getBookingSum = room => room.booking.sum;

    plotChart(xLabel, yLabel) {
        this.setYValuesCb(this.getBookingSum.bind(this));
        
        this.plotBarChart(this.data, this.xAxis, this.yAxis, this.x, 
            this.y, xLabel, yLabel, this.ticks, this.margin, this.width, this.height);
    }    
}
```

Comment: lamba-functions doesn't have context. It means that keyword 'this' links to around environment context. In this case it is equals to globalThis (for example, window in browsers), that usually doesn't have required method. I recommend to use classic function declaration in classes.

Comment: Did you try to call `getYValuesCB`  from `BookingsChart` instance?

Comment: `getValuesCB` is a  property in the class, not a method.

Comment: D3Chart.js:35 getYValuesCB:  ƒ getBookingSum(room) {
        return room.booking.sum;
    }

Comment: Where are you calling `this.getYValuesCB()`? What line is throwing the exception? Please show that as well.

Answer (score -1):

You got  `this.getYValuesCB is not a function` because you defined`getYValuesCB` as a `property` ( a null object in your case ) in your `class` not a `method`.

If you type :

```
console.log(typeof bookingsChart.getYValuesCB);
```

Where `bookingsChart` is an instance of `BookingsChart` you'll get this result:

```
object
```

That means `getYValuesCB` is a property.

However, in your case ( I expected that ) , you call `getYValues` as a method :

```
 bookingsChart.getYValuesCB();
```

This will invoke this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: bookingsChart.getYValuesCB is not a function
```

Indeed, in Javascript:

> Functions are a special type of objects, called functions objects.

You can create a function by calling the built-in function constructor:

```
this.getYValuesCB=new Function();
```

Or by assigning a function object to a property ( Recommended for you ) :

```
this.getYValuesCB = function () {
        // return initial value
    };
```

In this example, we have assigned a function object to the property `getDetails`, then we call it as a method from our instance.

```
class Book {
  constructor(type, author) {
    this.type = type;
    this.author = author;
    this.getDetails = function () {
      return this.type + " written by " + this.author;
    };
  }
}
var book = new Book("Fiction", "Peter King");
alert(book.getDetails()); // => Fiction written by Peter King
```

Comment: There is no `Book.getYValuesCB` in the OP's code?

Comment: it does see it as a function but then sees it as null
here are some logs:
`
D3Charts.js:35
getYValuesCB:  ƒ getBookingSum(room) {
        return room.booking.sum;
    }

D3Charts.js:35
getYValuesCB:  null
`

Comment: @Bergi, it was a typo mistake. I expected he called `getYValuesCB` from `BookingsChart` instance like this : `bookingsChart.getYValues()`.

Comment: yes in the entry point the child class is called:
`const bookingsChart = new BookingsChart(data, "bookings-chart");`

getYValues is set in the child class and use in the parent

Comment: I don't see what the question has to do with "functions are objects". Also `typeof` returns `"function"` for callable objects, not `"object"`.

Comment: @Bergi, it returns `object`  when you declare it `null` in the constructor : `this.getYValues=null` as @Steven did it. But as I mentioned when you declared it as a function : `this.getYValues=function(){}`it returns `function`.